# Check for ftp authentication output for bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, sh

I run an automated backup shell script, it works great, but for some reason the FTP blocks me for a few minutes. I would like to add a retry and wait feature. below is sample of my code.

```
   echo "Moving to external server"
   cd /root/backup/
/usr/bin/ftp -n -i $FTP_SERVER <<END_SCRIPT
   user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD
   mput $FILE
   bye
END_SCRIPT
```

after a failed login i get the message below

```
Authentication failed. Blocked.
Login failed.
Incorrect sequence of commands: PASS required after USER
```

i need to capture such output and make the code atempt to sleep for few minutes before trying again.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible for you to install additional programs onto the system of interest i encourage you to take a look at `lftp`.

With `lftp` it is possible to set paramters like the time between reconnects etc. manually.

To achieve your aim with `lftp` you have to invoke the following

```
lftp -u user,password ${FTP_SERVER} <<END
set ftp:retry-530 "Authentication failed"
set net:reconnect-interval-base 60
set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 10
set net:max-retries 10
<some more custom commands>
END
```

If the pattern after `ftp:retry-530` matches the 530 reply of the server `lftp` tries to reconnect every 60*10 seconds.

Comment: this surely solve my problem, but i would like to do it the hard way for the sake of learning. Exit interactive mode do logic operation then enter interactive mode again to continue the code.

Answer (score 1):

The message below is probably going to stderr instead of stdout so you will need to capture the stderr output first:

```
while true
do
  if ( script 2>&1 |grep -q 'Authentication failed' )
  then
    echo "authentication failed, sleeping for a while before trying again"
    sleep 60
  else
    #everything worked, break out of the while loop
    break
  fi  
done
```

Comment: Remember when I enter FTP command, it will become an interactive input this is why I use END_SCRIPT. How I can do logic like your code above in between?

Comment: if ( lftp ....... <<END
.....
....
...
END 2>&1 | grep -q 'Authentication failed' )